# How to use match filter in Mapbox react-native-mapbox-gl

Tags: ios, react-native, filter, maps, mapbox-gl-js

I'm getting the following error when trying to filter a `SymbolLayer` with `match`:

[image: error image]

Here's the `SymbolLayer` code:

```
<MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
  id="LayerRestaurant"
  filter={[
    'all',
    ['==', 'maki', 'restaurant'],
    ['match', 'name', 'Pita Pit', true, false],
  ]}
/>
```

Any ideas how can I make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

We can't mix the filters `==` and `match` with `react-native-mapbox-gl`.

So I just converted the `==` filter I was using to the `match` filter as well:

```
<MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
  id="LayerRestaurant"
  filter={[
    'all',
    ['match', ['get', 'maki'], 'restaurant', true, false],
    ['match', ['get', 'name'], 'Pita Pit', true, false],
  ]}
/>
```